# bluetooth is not working on my ubuntu 16.04 laptop

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

/etc/bluetooth contains following files :

input.conf
main.conf
network.conf
proximity.conf

I also tried to install bluetooth from Ubuntu Software . But still PC is neither able to search bluetooth nor be searched by other.

Please help me to configure bluetooth in my ubuntu-16.04 Dell PC.